# CSS Overflow fall back?

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, css

Is there a good fallback for browsers where CSS overflow doesn't work?  I'm coding a new layout that depends heavily on the overflow property but it seems android browsers doesn't support it so my layout is completely broken.  I'm using jquery already so adding a little extra code there won't be a big deal, I'm just wondering if there is an accepted way of mimicking the effect.

To be a little more detailed I have a carousel with a large width where I need it to cut off at the end of the page horizontally.  It works fine with just about everything but android browsers.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Overflow has existed for a long time, and should definitely be supported by any browser that isn't ancient (e.g. anything later than Netscape 4.7).

If your layout doesn't work in some browser, it's most likely because of something else. For example that the markup is not correct, so the elements doesn't end up as you think, or that you are trying to apply it to an element that isn't supported.

Comment: I thought that may be the case but a google search yielded this:
http://www.androidannoyances.com/post/51

If I take off overflow completely from the site it looks exactly like it does in the android browser.  It works on every other browser I've tried.